# What way is better for use gradle BOM and spring-boot(multimodular application)

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, gradle-plugin, spring-boot-gradle-plugin, maven-bom

I use `Gradle` to build my `spring-boot` application. What do I want?

I have a multimodular application where some modules are `spring-boot` applications. I want to get `BOM` spring dependencies in the parent project's Gradle file and use all libraries without versions.

Now I have the next configs:

```
 buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        }
    }

apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
```

And I duplicate this code in each module. I read `Gradle` [documentation](https://guides.gradle.org/building-spring-boot-2-projects-with-gradle/) and see this:

> The plugin itself does not automatically apply the Spring Dependency
>   Management plugin anymore. Instead it does react to the Spring
>   Dependency Management plugin being applied and configured with the
>   spring-boot-dependencies BOM (bill of materials. We will go into more
>   detail about the BOM support later in this post.)

And there is an example below:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'com.gradle.build-scan' version '1.16'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.0.5.RELEASE'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.0.5.RELEASE'
...
```

I'm confused. What variant is better? I try to change my code like this documentation and I get an error:

```
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':my-server:compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:.
     Required by:
         project :my-server
   > Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache:.
     Required by:
         project :my-server
   > Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:.
     Required by:
         project :my-server
   > Could not find org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:.
     Required by:
         project :my-server
   > Could not find org.projectlombok:lombok:.
     Required by:
         project :my-server
   > Could not find org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:.
     Required by:
         project :my-server
```

Answer (score 0):

You still need to define `repositories` for your dependencies. Add the below line to your build.gradle.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```